# Installing local packages with Meteor

Tags: meteor, meteorite, iron-router

I'm going through some Meteor tutorials trying to get up to speed, seems like a nice framework. However I'm having difficulty, perhaps because I'm overcomplicating things, with packages. I've installed iron-router and set up some routes, simple enough, apart from that the package is linked to from my projects route rather than being installed into my projects folder structure - I installed with mrt - and iron-router is serving the templates in it's examples folder. Deleting that folder kills the app. Manually installing irk-router into the packages folder for my project and ensuring smart.json is linking to it does nothing to help.

I've ready and searched for hours now but I'm guessing I'm doing something very off the wall as I can't see anyone else with this issue.

Are packages always global in the ./meteorite folder and linked to, or are they local? And if so how do you set them up?

Cheers.

EDIT: After some more tinkering I believe the issue is actually iron-router and not the local install. The app runs but I just have a white screen, I think iron-router is not able to locate my templates.

Comment: Please create git repo from your meteor app, push to github and put link in comment, so I can try help you with Iron-Router .

Comment: After you install package from atmospherejs (mrt add iron-router) then  that package is in Packages dir in your app

Comment: I noticed that sometimes you need to type `mrt install` or manually append name of the package ( iron-router) to .meteor/packages file.

Comment: Here you go: https://github.com/fingerpuk/microscope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I removed all the packages, manually deleted anything left over, and re-installed them with Meteorite. That was the only way to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`cd /usr/local/meteor/lib/ && npm install <module>`